# Сравнение строк при выборке

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM mess WHERE who='2' or whom='2' ORDER BY id DESC) as tmp
GROUP BY who, whom ORDER BY id DESC
```

Он делает выборку с конца таблицы и в итоге получается примерно так:

```
id    who    whom
13     2      1
11     1      2
 9     3      2
 7     2      3
 4     2      5
```

Как теперь сделать так, чтобы оставались только записи без повторений в who и whom, и с большим id.
То есть в итоге должно быть так:

```
id    who    whom
13     2      1
 9     3      2
 4     2      5
```

Может немного коряво объяснил, если что непонятно, уточняйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё нашёл ответ.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM mess WHERE who='2' or whom='2' ORDER BY id DESC) as tmp
GROUP BY LEAST( who, whom ) , GREATEST( who, whom ) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mess WHERE (who='2' or whom='2') and id > чего то (или 
max(id) ) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: А что значит id > чего-то(это чего? откуда брать это значение? или max(id)?) Пока не помогло. Всё выбирает.

Comment: ну какие тебе надо ид? все? оставить только max(id), если больше какого-то, то id>10, например

Comment: Нет, суть в том, что если есть запись who = 2 and whom = 1, то who = 1 and whom = 2 брать уже не нужно.

Comment: для этого стоит SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: Хоть мне и неизвестно больше какого значение должен быть id, да и max(id) не работает внутри WHERE, поробовал сделать такой запрос. Мне выдалось всё больше 100. Никакой уникальности.

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mess WHERE (who='2' or whom='2') and id > 100 ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: т.е. тебе надо уникальность по 2м столбцам?

Comment: Да, нужно именно так.